# How to create a Kafka consumer library to consume multiple topics

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have 'N' number of Kafka topics, where I need to consume messages from different topics and based on the business logic. I need to process/filter them and send it to service bus.I don't want to create a N number of kafka configurations to consume messages.I just want to make it as a library, where I can simply externalize the properties to pick and configure the consumers.So that I can just put the business logic inside my application. Did anyone have already done this kind of implementations before.Please let me know the best practices for this approach.

Edited: Here is my KafkaConsumerConfig looks like:

***KafkaConsumerConfig.java***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer}")
    private String keyDeserializer;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer}")
    private String valueDeserializer;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupIdConfig;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String autoOffsetResetConfig;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.client-id}")
    private String clientIdConfig;

    @Bean
    public KafkaReceiver receiver() {
        return new KafkaReceiver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupIdConfig);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetResetConfig);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to any number of topics with a single consumer via

```
KafkaConsumer#subscribe(Collection<String> topics)
```

Comment: I edited the post with the code which I have written for Kafka Config. Can you tell me how can I replace the ConsumerFactory to make it work.

Comment: Can you share your thought how to make kafkaconsumerconfig as a library. So I can just implement the listeners and my business logic.